# GetOpenFileName lpstrInitialDir (directory)... not working for URL (SharePoint)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, openfiledialog, getopenfilename

I bring up a `GetOpenFileName` dialog, enter a URL to a SharePoint sever, and it lets me browse that server using the Web Client Service (WebDAV mini-redirector).  I am trying to get the initial directory to come up as that URL, but it seems to ignore it (using `OPENFILENAME` struct's `lpstrInitialDir`).  Local paths work fine.

EDIT: Paul requested the form of the URL:  it's http://doc.name.com    I've also tried a trailing slash (both flavors) to see if that made a difference (saw some reference to that in another posted question).  It didn't seem to.

EDIT2: This does work if I use the WebDAV address instead of the HTTP URL (i.e., \doc.name.com\DavWWWRoot.  This doesn't solve my problem, as it's not a view of the site that users will recognize and will have difficulty working with.

Comment: Can you show the URL (or a censored version)? Are you specifying it as an HTTP URL or a UNC-style path?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is for vista, you can use the IFileOpenDialog, which lets you use an IShellItem as the default location, and it should be pretty easy to create a shell item that points to the sharepoint URL.

Comment: Thanks.  The vast majority of my userbase is on XP, so a Vista solution probably isn't going to get me off the hook.